# UIActivityViewController memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm presenting a UIActivityViewController using the following code (using ARC):

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cat",@"Dog" , nil]
                                                applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController  animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Running the program on iphone simulator with instruments "Leaks".
After presenting the view and clicking cancel:
Getting leak at the following line (100%):

```
    [self presentViewController:activityController  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the leak occurs on iPhone/iPad as well, I've encountered several cases where leaks are reported in the simulator, just to be gone when running on a device. Secondly, the problem might be that when you dismiss the activity controller you do so in a manner that doesn't correctly remove it, so check how you remove the activity controller after cancel.

Answer (score 0):

The `alloc` is balanced automatically by `ARC`. But handing over the `activityController` to self increases the reference count, and puts the object into an `autorelease pool`, if it exists. So, if your code runs in a thread that does not have an `autorelease pool`, this object will leak.

Comment: The code runs within the main thread, which runs by default in an autoreleasepool created in main.m. I created a single view based ios arc app using xcode, and all I added was a button to run the above share action. The leak still occurs.

Comment: You are right. The leaked object is an OS_dispatch_queue. I think you should report this to Apple.